# PostgreSQL count multiple columns of the same table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to count some columns from a table in PostgreSQL.

For each column count I have some conditions and I want to have all in one query. My problem is the fact that I don't get the expected results in counting because I tried to apply all the conditions for the entire data set.

The table:

| column1 | column2 | column3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| UUID10 | UUID20 | UUID30 |
| `NULL` | UUID21 | `NULL` |
| `NULL` | UUID22 | UUID31 |
| UUID11 | UUID20 | UUID30 |

This is what I tried so far:

```
SELECT
   COUNT(DISTINCT column1) AS column1_count,
   COUNT(DISTINCT column2) AS column2_count,
   COUNT(DISTINCT column3) AS column3_count
FROM TABLE
WHERE 
   column2 IN ('UUID20', 'UUID21', 'UUID22')       
   AND column1 = 'UUID10'  -> this condition should be removed from this where clause
   OR column3 IN ('UUID30', 'UUID31')
```

Result:

| column1_count | column2_count | coumn3_count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 3 | 2 |

The result in not correct because I should have column1_count = 1. I mean, this is what the query does, but is not what I intended. So I thought to have some constrains for column2 and column3 in a subquery, and having a another condition just for column1.

A second try:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
    column1
    column2,
    column3
    FROM TABLE
    WHERE  
    column2 IN ('UUID20', 'UUID21', 'UUID22') 
    OR column3 IN ('UUID30', 'UUID31')
) x
WHERE
column1 = 'UUID10'
```

Result:

| column1_count | column2_count | coumn3_count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |

Because the last condition on column1 is restricting my result, I end up having 1 for all the counts.
How can I apply different conditions for counting each column?

I would try not to use `UNION` if is possible. Maybe there can be made some subqueries in another way than what I tried so far. I just have to find a way for the constraint for the column1, to not be on the same `WHEN` clause as for the column2 and column3.

Comment: What is your desire output?

Comment: "I mean, this is what the query does, but is not what I intended."  Your question does not explain what you intend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think* you want conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN column1 = 'UUID10' THEN column1 END) AS column1_count,
       COUNT(DISTINCT column2) AS column2_count,
       COUNT(DISTINCT column3) AS coumn3_count
FROM TABLE
WHERE column2 IN ('UUID20', 'UUID21', 'UUID22') OR      
      column3 IN ('UUID30', 'UUID31');
```

I assume that you are aware that `COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN column1 = 'UUID10' THEN column1 END)` is not particularly useful code.  It returns 1 or 0 depending on whether the value is present.  I assume your code is actually more interesting.

Comment: I was aware of what you said and thank you for you answer.
I tried to came up with an abstract example to explain my problem, but I think your suggestion is helpful.